# Convert Really Long Number String To INT64

Tags: vb.net

Trying to convert a number string into an INT64 in VB.NET.  The number I am testing with is 12804494279291877304.
The error I am getting is `"Value was either too large or too small for an Int64."`
Code sample below.

```
BigInt = CLng(EncodeNumber)
```

Comment: Which part of too large do you not understand? Lets say 2^64 is 20.000 trilion. Your number is 12.000 trilion. Since Integer has to reserve half for positive and half for negative numbers you are trying to put 12.000 trilion value into 10.000 trilion holder. Use unsinged integer  (UInt) if you are sure it will only be a positive number, that way you can hold 20.000 trilion positive numbers.

Comment: "too large" seems a pretty obvious error to me. I hope you aren't asking what it means? Maybe you are asking if there's an alternative data type you can use?

Comment: `Dim ul As UInt64  UInt64.TryParse("12804494279291877304", ul)`...

Answer (score 6):

It's too big, [doesn't fix in a INT64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=netframework-4.8). It would fit in a UINT64.

```
    Dim v As UInt64

    v = UInt64.Parse("12804494279291877304")
```

Like @Çöđěxěŕ said, using [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_UInt64_TryParse_System_String_System_UInt64__) allow the use of proper error handling.

```
If Not UInt64.TryParse("12804494279291877304", v) Then
    ' Handle wrong input
End If
```

Comment: IMHO https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3):

Your number is too big for `Int64`, so you could use `BigInteger`, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8

You can use unsigned Int64 as others suggest but beware that it won't hold negative numbers and also has a limit of 18446744073709551615